# compare two video then cut the difference

Tags: video, video-processing, video-editing

I have 2 video files with the same content, but coming from a different source. They have a slight difference in 'cut' and language dubbing, meaning one can be missing a shot compared to the other.

I have a other language dubbed that is correctly timed for one file (call it A), and because of the different cut, a bit off for the other (call it B).

The thing is that “A” also has low quality, while “B” is of better quality, and original language dubbed.

I basically need to fix the timing of the dubbed to match B.

In order to do so, i need to locate the missing/additional shots between the 2 videos, so i know where to cut it..

This is realistic if i have only one pair of files, however i have 20 pair of files ! I would like to automate this search, and basically compare the 2 files at different points in time, and find where they diverge.

How can I do this? what software do I use for windows?

Since file A has other dubbed language, the comparison method should be exact enough to detect content difference..

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the individual frame are the same quality size etc, you could use an approach like this:

1. Start at first frame of both videos
2. Read frame from both videos and compare
3. If the same go back to previous step and read in next frame
4. If different, store the frame number read next up to the next x frames of video A until you find a frame that matches the current fame in video B (case where video A had the extra frames)
5. If you reach x and do not find a match in the step above, read next up to the next x frames of video B until you find a frame that matches the current fame in video A (case where video B had the extra frames)
6. Assuming you found a match above, then go back to step 2 and continue to work through both video files

The value of X would control how far ahead you are prepared to search to find the same frame.

Python with OpenCV would be one common choice of language/tool to implement this - a skeleton example to show opening the video files and comparing (the is not tested or ruining, its just to give an example steer):

```js
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim as ssim

capture = cv2.VideoCapture("videoA.mp4")
capture2 = cv2.VideoCapture("videoB.mp4")
simlarityIndexThreshold =  // the value you want as your threshold

while True:
    f, frameA = capture.read()
    f2, frameB = capture2.read()

    if (frameA.empty() || frameB.emnpty()
        break
    
    simlarityIndex = ssim(farmeA, frameB)
    if(simlarityIndex < simlarityIndexThreshold):
        //Frames are differnt so do your work to skip ahead here
```

There are multiple ways to compare similarity between images in OpenCV so it would be worth you doing some searching to decide which you want to use - the above method is documented here:https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#compare-ssim